# NSViewContoller создается два раза

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos

В одном видеоуроке увидел реализацию переключения между двумя видами. Суть в том, что в главном окне (`MainMenu.xib`) есть Custom View, который привязан к `AppController`. Созданы также отдельно два класса `FriendViewController` и `ChatViewController`, которые унаследованы от `NSViewContoller` и привязаны, соответсвенно, к собственным .xib файлам, в которых имеются Custom View.

Проект выполнялся с использованием **ARC.**

Проблем с переключением вьюшек не возникло. Но они начались, когда я пытался реализовать делегирование. Для этого я описал простенький протокол:

```
@protocol viewSelector <NSObject>
@required
-(void)changeView:(NSInteger)viewID;
@end
```

Затем объявил в FriendViewController свойство-делегат:

```
@interface FriendsViewController : NSViewController<NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource>
{
    __unsafe_unretained id <viewSelector> delegate;
}

@property (assign, nonatomic)id <viewSelector> delegate;
-(IBAction)tableItemSelected:(id)sender;

@end
```

В AppController (который отвечает за главное окно) объявил, что он реализует мой протокол:

```
#import "FriendsViewController.h"

@interface AppController : NSObject <viewSelector>

@property (strong) IBOutlet NSView *ourView;
@property (strong) NSViewController *ourViewController;

@end
```

При создании главного view делаю так, чтобы подставлялся FriendViewController и сразу присваивался делегат:

```
@implementation AppController

@synthesize ourView = _ourView;
@synthesize ourViewController = _ourViewController;

NSString *const friendControllerName = @"FriendsViewController";
NSString *const chatControllerName = @"ChatViewController";

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    NSLog(@"Nib was loaded");
    [[_ourViewController view] removeFromSuperview];
    self.ourViewController = [[FriendsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:friendControllerName bundle:nil];
    [_ourView addSubview:[_ourViewController view]];
    [(FriendsViewController *)_ourViewController setDelegate:self];
    [[_ourViewController view] setFrame:[_ourView bounds]];
    [[_ourViewController view] setAutoresizingMask:NSViewHeightSizable|NSViewWidthSizable];
}

-(void)changeView:(NSInteger)viewID
{
    NSLog(@"Message recieved!");
}
```

В итоге, при дебаге, выясняется, что для FriendViewController конструктор вызывается два раза:

после того, как вызывается:

```
self.ourViewController = [[FriendsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:friendControllerName bundle:nil];
```

и, внезапно, после того, как добавляем FriendViewController на передний план:

```
[_ourView addSubview:[_ourViewController view]];
```

В связи с этим, метод

```
[(FriendsViewController *)_ourViewController setDelegate:self];
```

присваивает делегат первой копии `FriendViewController`, в то время, как отображается вторая копия, в которой `delegate = nil`. Сообщения уходят в никуда, тратится лишняя память.

Вопрос: почему `FriendViewController` создается 2 раза и как это поправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос решен. Ошибка была в файле FriendsViewController - был создан лишний object, тогда как достаточно было воспользоваться File's Owner